# Fastest way to do scalar vector multiplication in OpenCL

Tags: opencl

I have two input float4 vectors, say `float4 A` & `float4 B`. And an output array of float4 vectors `float4 C[4]` I operation I intend to do is

```
C[0] += A.s0 * B
C[1] += A.s1 * B
C[2] += A.s2 * B
C[3] += A.s3 * B
```

Is there any OpenCL built-in function to do this operation (or) any alternative way to speed up this operation?

Edit 1:
I've already tried the below option using built-in `mad()` function. There was no improvement in performance.

```
C[0].s0 = mad(A.s0, B.s0, C[0].s0);
C[0].s1 = mad(A.s0, B.s1, C[0].s1);
C[0].s2 = mad(A.s0, B.s2, C[0].s2);
C[0].s3 = mad(A.s0, B.s3, C[0].s3);
```

Comment: The OpenCL C compiler will probably use the fused multiply-add operation either way for simple cases like yours. Try disabling compile-time optimizations by passing `-cl-opt-disable` to clBuildProgram() and run your benchmarks again.

Comment: I tried disabling the optimizations while building the program. The execution time is a lot different than with optimization. But the question is different. Is there any other better/faster way (other than mentioned above) to do this operation?